# Chrome doesn't save extension settings and loses state after closing all windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, cookies

In Google Chrome, when I change the setting "Site access" to "All sites" on extensions it only saves this state until I close all windows (but not necessarily quit). As an example, upon re-opening the a window not only has it forgotten this setting, but it also locked Bitwarden even though previously it only locked after restarting the browser (as it should). Even setting Bitwarden to never lock the vault doesn't fix this. This doesn't seem to be a Bitwarden-specific thing as the "Site access" setting is reset on all extensions.

I'm suspecting something is broken and is causing it to lose internal state when I close all windows. I'm using Google Chrome 98 on macOS Monterey. Restarting Chrome doesn't fix this. Reinstalling the browser did fix it, but only temporarily, which is confusing.

Does this maybe have something to do with the cookie setting "Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows"? I enabled that at one point to try it out but have since disabled it again since pauses Sync which is annoying. It almost seems like this setting is stuck partially on as Chrome is deleting *some* data when I close all windows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a bug in Chrome as I've been able to reproduce and fix it. The issue seems to appear in my system context when the setting "Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows" is activated. Deactivating this setting doesn't fully deactivate it and continues to remove some (but not all) browser state after closing all windows even after disabling it. Removing Chrome's files (effectively reinstalling it) solved this issue. I likely had this issue reappear because I enabled and then disabled that setting after previously reinstalling Chrome. Maybe I can try to look into reporting this as a bug.