# On macOS Chrome is not running in the background and seems to shut off when all windows are closed

Tags: macos, google-chrome, permissions, notifications

Chrome used to be active in the background when all windows are closed but the app is still running. It seems something (my settings, Chrome's settings, some update?) changed this behavior. Bitwarden locks the vault even though it's set to keep it open until I restart the browser and I'm not getting desktop notifications *until* I open a window (even an empty tab will do) and then they all come in. It seems like it's not running background processes when there are no open tabs. It also seems to forgot extension state when all tabs are closed.

Background notifications and Bitwarden not locking when tabs are closed have worked in the past with Chrome. Chrome is in fact running.

Is there a way to change this behavior? I've tried reinstalling Chrome to no avail. Is there maybe a macOS setting that's preventing it from doing this in the background? It does have sufficient permissions as far as I can tell.

I'm using Chrome 104 and macOS Monterey 12.2.1. I've asked a [related (unanswered) question](https://superuser.com/questions/1704498/chrome-doesnt-save-extension-settings-and-loses-state-after-closing-all-windows) here before but what I thought had fixed the problem did not actually work long-term and now I'm also having issues with notifications not being delivered in the background.

Comment: You can test for Chrome still running with Activity Monitor. I can't answer for whatever Bitwarden might do under specific circumstances.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am sure that Chrome is still running, the dock icon is present and it's in Activity Monitor. The issue is that Chrome isn't running notification web workers (or whatever does notifications) in the background. This has also worked in the past.